# VNC to a linux desktop in HiDPI mode won't scale properly

Tags: linux, osx, vnc, display

I have a linux mint Cinnamon desktop running in HiDPI.

When I try to connect to it with a VNC client from my macbook (retina/hidpi display), the desktop shows up about 4x too big.

I tried with mac's built in VNC viewer and also the real VNC client.

I tried different settings in Real VNC's expert mode preferences - Scaling - AspectFit, 25%, etc; nothing seems to change the scaling.

Comment: Is there a 'Fit to window' toggle anywhere? Try that and see if it works.

Comment: @Mioriin that button doesn't work.

Comment: did you try -geometry widthxheight when starting vncserver?